# Solr Suggester multiple field match

Tags: solr, autosuggest

I am trying to implement **solr suggester** for my application that matches field A equals to *something* and field B equal to less than 2016

I need to use these two fields to match something is solr using Suggester

Can some one lay out the details on how to implement
I read the documentation but its a bit confusing